# When is a simple tensor equivalent to natural multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, tensors

Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain; let $M, N$ be $R$-modules.

Let $x_1 \in M$ and let $x_2 \in N$.  When does the following equivalence hold?

$$x_1 \otimes x_2 = x_1x_2$$

The textbook I'm reading often makes these conclusions without justifying them.

I'll present an example of such an instance.

Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$, and consider $M \otimes_R K$.

For $x \in M$ and for $a,b \in R$, $b \neq 0$, we have $xab^{-1}$ = $xa \otimes b^{-1}$.

Comment: Unless there is some multiplication defined on $\;M\times N\;$ , something that doesn't *usually* happen at all, the expression $\;x_1x_2\;$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Your example is waaay another matter: since $\;a,b\in R\;$ and $\;M\;$ is $\;R-$ module, the product $\;xab^{-1}\;$ makes sense...

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani, in that case you should **not** write $=$, because the modules are not the same.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, of course. You're right.

Comment: Everyone seems to be assuming that $b^{-1} \in R$, it is only assumed that $b \in R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element $xab^{-1}$ is an element in the localization $S^{-1}M$ where $S = R \setminus \{0\}$.  There is a natural isomorphism $M \otimes_R S^{-1}R \simeq S^{-1}M$ defined by $m \otimes \frac{a}{b} \mapsto \frac{ma}{b}$.  Here $S^{-1}R$ is the ring $K$.

In general writing $x_1 \otimes x_2 = x_1x_2$ doesn't make sense unless you are invoking some type of explicit isomorphism between the tensor product and a ring or module in which the multiplication makes sense.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jim, I think I understand the connection now.